# How to make div responsive with inner content without bootstrap

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to make a  `div` and its inner content responsive , so when i resize window `div` also resize same on window size without **bootstrap**.

like this in **bootstrap**:

```
        <div id="mapImage1"  class="col-sm-12" style="position: relative;">
            <img  src .... />

        </div>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're avoiding Bootstrap? I don't really see a reason why you would want to make a page responsive by yourself instead of relying on fully working, widely tested CSS.

Comment: Are you just wanting the image to be 100% width? if so just remove the col-sm-12 and give both mapImage1 and the img a width of 100%.  With bootstrap, to make images repsonsive, I think there is a class: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Answer (score 0):

try this css:

```
    /* Show in default resolution screen*/
#container2 {
width: 960px;
position: relative;
margin:0 auto;
line-height: 1.4em;
}

/* If in mobile screen with maximum width 479px. The iPhone screen resolution is 320x480 px (except iPhone4, 640x960) */    
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){
    #container2 { width: 90%; }
}
```

Here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CG9WN/605/

Comment: ya but its for content what about if in div contain inner div image or other

Comment: i cant undetstand your purpose but when a div is responsive all of childs must be responsive too .

Comment: i updated my demo for adding image tag and another inner div , all of them is responsive http://jsfiddle.net/CG9WN/606/